# Possible to use LESS variable as a @supports rule?

Tags: css, less

I'm trying to set up my LESS so that if I set a variable `@fallback` to true, the CSS renders as if I were using an older browser that doesn't support new features, which is really useful for testing.

I have a conditional statement that changes the `@feature` to test support for, but the problem is LESS seems not to accept variables inside the `@supports` statement.

It renders literally as `@supports not (@feature)`.

I tried `@supports not (~'@{feature}')` and that didn't work either.

Is there any way to get around this?

```
  // Flex Fallback

  @fallback = true;

  & when (@fallback = true) {@feature = 'x';}
  & when (@fallback = false) {@feature = 'display: grid';}

  @supports not (@feature) {
    // Fallback stuff
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

LESS does not appear to support variable interpolation in `@supports` rules.

In this case, since you're really just looking to toggle the `@supports` at-rule itself on and off, you can work around this by placing your fallback rules in a mixin, and outputting them with or without the `@supports` at-rule based on your condition:

```
// Flex Fallback

@fallback: true;

.fallback() {
  // Fallback stuff
}

& when (@fallback = true) {
  .fallback();
}

& when (@fallback = false) {
  @supports not (display: grid) {
    .fallback();
  }
}
```

Comment: That's really funny, I was just working on it and came up with the same solution. It's not as dry as being able to use a variable directly, but still pretty good. Thanks!